# CMake unable to find mysqlclient library

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I'm using `CMake` to generate a makefile to compile a C++ project that uses the boost, eigen, and mysqlclient libraries.

During the make process the code seems to compile, but then at the linking stage I get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
```

I have the line `target_link_libraries(my_executable mysqlclient)`
in my `CMakeLists.txt` file. When I remove that line, then I no longer get that error message, but then I get a long list of undefined symbols errors (all having to do with mysql). 
The project builds correctly in Xcode, so I know that at least the mysql client libraries are set up on my machine.
Any tips, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `FindMySQL.make` package from Kitware (save the file here: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeUserFindMySQL (updated link: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/contrib/modules/FindMySQL ) as `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindMySQL.cmake`), then find the library:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")    
find_package(MySQL)
```

Finally, your link step in cmake should be replaced with

```
target_link_library(myexecutable ${MYSQL_LIBRARY})
```

`${MYSQL_LIBRARY}` should contain the fully qualified path to the library file that you want to link with

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggested: saved the file as FindMySQL.cmake and then added those two lines to CMakeLists.txt. When I do that, I get the following output from CMake: CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:64 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMySQL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "MySQL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MySQL" with any of
  the following names:

    MySQLConfig.cmake
    mysql-config.cmake

Comment: I have edited the answer to fix the module path problem. I had assumed that you had that setup correctly and downloaded the file to correct place.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did have the module path set up, but still gives the same error.

Comment: I'm using MAMP to run MySQL, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Could you look if the ${MYSQL_LIBRARY} variable is picking up the correct value? Does that file `libmysqlclient.so` exist in your system?

Comment: It looks as if the MYSQL_LIBRARY variable is not even being set. At least it does not appear on the list in the CMake gui. Is there another way to check? I do have a variable called MySQL_DIR, with value MySQL_DIR-NOTFOUND.

Comment: Do you know where your MySQL client libraries are being saved. Can you confirm that it is there in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119057/discussion-between-aaron-schurger-and-subzero).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply include/link to the [mysqlclient C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api.html), without creating a cmake file, you could use the [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindPkgConfig.html) from cmake:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(MySQL REQUIRED mysqlclient>=5.7)
```

and the related vars

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MySQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MySQL_LIBRARIES})
```